# Obtaining group-level estimate of quantity, for e.g. correlation

Tags: estimation, fixed-effects-model, point-estimation

say I have multiple estimates of correlation between source A and source B, for multiple subjects. the number of estimates vary between subjects. for example, subject 1 might have 10 estimates of correlation between source A & B, subject 2 might have 50 estimates. I want to combine all these estimates to obtain a group-level estimate of the correlation.

Apart from estimating a multi-level model (which is mathematically difficult in this case, since quantity of interest is actually *not* correlation), I have two options:

1. simply average all available estimates to obtain a group-level estimate of correlation.
2. first average estimates within subject for each subject, to obtain subject-level estimates of correlation. then, average the within-subject averages to obtain a group-level estimate of correlation.

which of the above two options would you choose and why?

Comment: Do you have the raw data or only the correlation estimates.

Comment: I ask because I think a meta analysis might be an approach you can take.

Comment: also have the raw data

Answer (score 0):

I would calculate the individual-level mean correlation and then use the median of these means as the group correlation. Mean can be easily affected by extreme values, but median doesn't have this disadvantage.